# AWS - Can I launch nodes under a DNS domain (Auto Scale Group)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, fqdn

**Use Case**

I'm working on an application that uses Presto, and for Presto, I have to set up HTTPS traffic internally (for security compliance reasons).

For this, I preferably need the nodes' FQDN to be in the same domain.  E.g. myhost1.mydomain.com, myhost2.mydomain.com.

**My Question**

AWS automatically gives a FQDN like ip-10-20-30-40.ec2.internal.  So, my question is:

Is there a way I can have a new node automatically be created with a FQDN like myhost1.mydomain.com?  I know I can create internal "hosted zones" and DNS records for my hosts pretty easily, but I can't figure out how to make that the default domain for a new host.

Also, just FYI, I'm doing this for an auto-scale group; but I suspect that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Amazon EC2 starts, it can run a script passed in via User Data.

You could code this script to create a `CNAME` record in Amazon Route 53 that points to the IP address of the instance.

I'm not sure how you'd necessarily determine the *number* within the name, so you could just create a random name. Also, it might be tricky to *remove* the `CNAME` entry when the instance is terminated. One way to both assign and remove the record would be to use [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html), which allows code to be triggered *outside* of the instance itself. It's more complex but would be fully effective.

Comment: Yeah, I've been debating using user-data for this.  I saw a good article about implementing dynamic DNS purely with life-cycle hooks, and I could manipulate the fqdn with the user data script as well.  I also debated just modifying the hosts file for all hosts in the cluster as this is just to help with "internal communication security"; the DNS names don't need to resolve outside those hosts.  May come back and accept this later depending on what else comes through.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Presto, but here's a couple of ideas.

First, if you are using an AWS managed load balancer, you can enable HTTPS between it and the instance using self-signed cert:  the load balancer will NOT validate the cert, so your connection will be secure.

If that's not what you need, take a look at DHCP option sets for your VPC - I believe you can set your own domain name, rather than use the default ec2.internal.

Comment: Thanks; the later option sounds interesting, will check it out.  I need secure communications between all nodes in the distributed presto cluster, so a load balancer won't help with this particular situation (though I do use them on the query side in various places to help with HA).